# java multipart file how to find mime type if the file extension modified?

Tags: java, file, upload, mime-types, content-type

Java file upload
 getcontentType
  mimetype

always gives extension based on the extension passed
 How to check if some one passing javascript file with extension changed as pdf.

```
1.  MimetypesFileTypeMap mimeTypesMap = new MimetypesFileTypeMap();
            doc.setMimeType(mimeTypesMap.getContentType(file.getOriginalFilename()));

2. file.getContentType()
```

// works based on extension

Comment: Have a look at Apache Tika : http://tika.apache.org/

Comment: apache tika not works with multipart file

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both solution you shared not worked for me too. (getContentType..)
In my search I found this [this](https://chidokun.github.io/2021/10/mime-type-and-upload-file-problem/en/) sharing.

This solution is using Apache tika in validation and works with MultipartFile!

Utils method;

```
public class FileUtils {
    public static String getRealMimeType(MultipartFile file) {
        AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
        Detector detector = parser.getDetector();
        try {
            Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
            TikaInputStream stream = TikaInputStream.get(file.getInputStream());
            MediaType mediaType = detector.detect(stream, metadata);
            return mediaType.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return MimeTypes.OCTET_STREAM;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller method;

```
@PostMapping(path = "/check-real-type", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Response> checkRealType(@RequestPart MultipartFile file) {
    String mimeType = FileUtils.getRealMimeType(file);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new Response(mimeType));
}
```

Dependency in pom.xml;

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be used to obtain file extension.
//It will return extension like these png,jpp,jpeg, etc.
String fileExtension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());